How do I say in a legal document that I was pissed without sounding like an a**h0l3?
I am trying to write something describing my encounter with a state worker.  The situation was regarding something that happened several years earlier and for some reason, these state employees keep showing up like it's their first time (more than 5 times every 3-9 months.)  So my being a little pissed is an understatement; however, acknowledging this is an important part of the description of this particular encounter being that although it was a less than 20 minute conversation, it snowballed into something else entirely.  And explaining my state of mind speaks to the reason for the way I responded.
So, my direct question is this.
How do I say that I spoke to these people in a pissed off way (and of course also saying without saying that there is/was a perfectly logical reason for this.)

If discretion is the better part of valor, you can be measured (without attitude) and get the same point across. Which is, not writing to complain, but asking for ... a refund, a different process, an exception, being considered under another category, etc.  Proving that the worker was a pest will buy you no better treatment. No incentive to please the public.

How is your document a legal one?

@Lambie As opposed to one for which you might be sued.

I doubt anybody would be sued for writing a statement. exasperation led me to use inappropriate language.

Are you saying you acted pissed off at the time, or that you are pissed off now, or both?

Also: are you trying to state that your attitude was entirely justified or that it might have been excessive?

Perhaps I was justifiably exasperated and irate

"I acknowledge that [at such and such a time] I had, regrettably, been provoked into frustration and I allowed my temper to get the better of me."

There are a few things you want to accomplish here.

Acknowledge that you know your behavior was regrettable or unfortunate.
Assert that your behavior is understandable. Justified takes a strong viewpoint that you don't necessarily need to defend. An enemy may say he understood your reaction without believing it was justified.
Frame your feelings in neutral terms as frustration, which is simply a reaction to the unpleasant situation. Again this is something both sides are more likely agree is a less caustic interpretation of events.
Frame this as a temporary suspension of your otherwise acceptable character. You weren't at your best, which is normally quite good.

Example:

I regrettably, if not understandably, allowed my frustration to get the best of me.

The if not accomplishes two things. First, it's not but. But is often interpreted as ignore everything I just said, and could come off as you saying you have no regrets at all. Second, if not sounds stilted, matching the rest of the phrasing. This helps show that you are, even in this statement, showing restraint and trying to act civilized. Maybe overly civilized. In other words, the reader should interpret this as you bring entirely generous and being the bigger person, when you are entirely justified in calling out the others in the situation in far less flattering terms.

It sounds like you reached a tipping point:

The point at which a series of small changes or incidents becomes
significant enough to cause a larger, more important, and often
irreversible change. Source: Oxford English
Dictionary (login required)

And then you took out [something] on someone:

to treat someone badly because you are upset or angry, even if they have done nothing wrong
Source: Cambridge Dictionary

So, maybe: “After a seemingly endless series of repetitive visits with no resolution, I finally reached my tipping point and took out my frustration on the worker.
